# Jquery $.ajax Get response conflicting with nested passing of 'this' object to 'success' callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am trying to do a jquery `$.ajax` `Get` inside a method of a class. The data supplied by the `Get` request to be used in the callback function on success and also the class needs to be modified inside the same callback. So, I had to `.apply` the callback on the **`this`** identifier of the original class since otherwise ,inside the callback, **`this`** was getting replaced locally. But while applying callback to **`this`** the data returned by `Get` is coming as `undefined`. How do I work around this problem. Any help appreciated.

```
var tableblock = function(tablename){
     this.tablename = tablename;
     this.numusers = 0;
     this.userpool = new Array();

     this.addme = function(){
        bodyContent = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "controllers/bestpals.php",
            data: "addpal=1&palname="+userid+"&nocache="+Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),
            error: function(xhr, statusText){alert('could not add pal. refresh page.');},
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg); // this will give undefined when .apply(this) 
                myid = msg;
                syncpals(this,true);
            }.apply(this) // using this alert(msg) above gives undefined 
        });
     };
 }
```

Comment: apply calls a function immediately. I don't think this is what you want to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but there's no such thing as classes in JavaScript

Comment: should have used .bind(this) instead of apply. That is definitely one of the solutions. But I will go with the lanzz's solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide a `context` parameter in your ajax configuration; all ajax callbacks will be called in that context (i.e., `this` inside the callback will refer to the value you pass as `context` in your `$.ajax()` call):

```
SomeClass.prototype.methodName = function() {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        context: this    // callbacks will be called with the same context that methodName() is running in
        ....
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), not [`.apply(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). `bind` changes the `this` pointer of a function, while `apply` actually runs the function in the new context.

Comment: Although `bind` is very recent and not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `bind` not `apply`. `bind` creates a new function that calls the wrapped one whilst setting `this`; `apply` calls the function straight away as soon as `addme()` runs.

However `bind` is an ECMAScript Fifth Edition feature, so you'd need to do one of:

1. [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) `bind` for older browsers;
2. use the jQuery equivalent [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/);
3. use the `context` argument to `ajax`, which sets `this` explicitly;
4. remember `var that= this;` in `addme` and use the enclosed `that` reference in the inner function.

Comment: I am going with Number 3. It just looks the cleanest way of doing it. :) Number 4 is a bit tricky because my subsequent modifications to 'that' will not finally reflect on this i suppose